# Flutter - abstract class varible debugging crash

Tags: flutter, debugging, crash

It works fine in my old projects, but when I create new projects in the current version, the debug feature does not work. The app crashes and I can't see where the error is.

https://youtu.be/JIYWh6R30LM <--

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\Users\hakki\fvm\default
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (3 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hakki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\hakki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\hakki\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\hakki\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.134
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.77

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This is the debug error;

F/libc    ( 7242): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xc8d07ffc in tid 7269 (1.ui), pid 7242 (ample.testdebug)

---

Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.190920.001/5891938:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2022-08-02 06:59:55+0000
pid: 7242, tid: 7269, name: 1.ui  >>> com.example.testdebug <<<
uid: 10135
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xc8d07ffc
eax cb6eb300  ebx cad21248  ecx c7788021  edx 1cc5fe14
edi cb695c00  esi c8d081f0
ebp c8d08038  esp c8d08000  eip ca962a9c
backtrace:
#00 pc 01a51a9c  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#01 pc 019ea970  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#02 pc 019ea2f3  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#03 pc 01b9f783  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#04 pc 01b9f50b  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#05 pc 01b9f435  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#06 pc 01aaa0db  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
.............................
#253 pc 01b8e223  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#254 pc 01b8e223  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
#255 pc 01b8e223  /data/app/com.example.testdebug-mDSVnJJF3ugKoNR2G0oGbw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: d973b44b1f88a49d7198234b2ecbee11cbdea747)
Lost connection to device.
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"76","method":"resume","params":{"isolateId":"isolates/233260206756375"}}

---

For simplicity, I create an empty class and derive another class from it. I aim to assign this to a variable and read the null values, but it gives an error.

```
class TestClass extends TestAbstractClass<TestClass> {
  String? name;

  TestClass({this.name});

  @override
  factory TestClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TestClass(
        name: json["name"],
      );

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
      };

  @override
  TestClass fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TestClass.fromJson(json);
}

abstract class TestAbstractClass<T> {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}
```

If I run the method below and stop at the 'var b =123' line and try to read the value of 'a', the program would crash and give the above error. I don't know what this is about. I changed versions and checked if gradle maybe related to kotlin version. I didn't get results.

```
  testMethod() {
    var a = TestClass();
    var b = 123;
  }
```

If I don't derive from abstract class then debug works as it should

Comment: Please write your code here as well. I'm aware some is visible in the linked video, but having it written out makes it easier for people to copy it and test it themselves

Comment: At your request, I edited my post and added my simplified example. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean?

Comment: Yes many times. There is no problem in my projects with Flutter 2.5.3. When I replace the android folder of my old projects with the one I just created, the problem still does not occur, but I want to understand what is doing this. I can't downgrade to gradle versions in my old projects. I'm starting to think that the problem is related to gradle or kotlin.